# how to set custom python path in catkin

Tags: ros, python, catkin, package.xml, manifest.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I used `<export><python path="..."/></export>` in manifest.xml with rosbuild, is there way to set similar thing in catkin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70960/how-to-set-custom-python-path-in-catkin/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2013-08-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should do this with an environment hook, see:

http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/user_guide/environment.html

http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin_add_env_hooks

https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/indigo-devel/core/roslib/env-hooks/10.ros.sh.em

https://github.com/ros/roslisp/blob/master/env-hooks/99.roslisp.sh

However, you should reevaluate why you need to do this. Instead you should install your python code into a place where it can be on the path automatically.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1